# Best pattern to structure and implement aggregate (or similar) method in tree node data

Tags: java, design-patterns, generics, tree

I have a problem when implementing aggregate (or alike) methods on a hierarchy of tree node data. As can be seen Generics is little bit overused here which is not satisfactory to me, so my question is: 
**is there a better way to implement it (possibly avoiding casts from Object in aggregate methods down the hierarchy) ?**

Current situation (stripped of unrelated details):

```
public interface AggregableTreeData<T extends AggregableTreeData> {
  void aggregate(T from);   
}

public abstract class FruitTreeData<T extends FruitTreeData<?>> 
      implements AggregableTreeData<T> {

  private BigDecimal size = BigDecimal.ZERO;

  @Override
  public void aggregate(T from) {
    this.size = this.size.add(from.size);
  }
}

public class OrangeTreeData<T extends OrangeTreeData<?>> 
    extends  FruitTreeData<T> {

  private boolean ripened = false;

  @Override
  public void aggregate(T from) {
    this.ripened = this.ripened || from.ripened;
  }
}
```

Additionally I have a method, performing tree data aggregation, which looks like:

```
//child.getData() and node.getData() is of type <T extends AggregableTreeData<T>>
void aggregateNode(TreeNode node) {
  for (TreeNode child : node.getChildren()) {
    aggregateNode(child);
    node.getData().aggregate(child.getData());
  }
}
```

Comment: "which is not satisfactory to me", why ?

Comment: It will be difficult to avoid generics since in [java method overriding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Java) works only with invariant parameter types. May be you look at the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comment: unsatisfactory - because the only reason for generics here (and ugly constructs like "FruitTreeData<T extends FruitTreeData<?>>") is limitation of java method overriding. However, visitor pattern seems promising, I'll try that and post a better solution if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks pretty much like a job for the composite pattern.